# ESP32 - JPEGDecoder from SPIFFS

Tags: esp32

Hello i've try to decode JPG image from FS so, i create and upload spiffs image (using /data directory and Arduino Ide Plugin )

On every jpg i've same error: "pjpeg_decode_init() failed with status 19"

here is my same code:

```
#include <TFT_eSPI.h> // Hardware-specific library
#include <SPI.h>
#include "GfxUi.h"

TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI(); // Invoke custom library

#define DEBUG
#define LOAD_SPIFFS

GfxUi ui = GfxUi(&tft);

void writeFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path, const char * message);
void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path);
void listDir(fs::FS &fs, const char * dirname, uint8_t levels);

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Start");
  SPIFFS.begin(true);
  tft.begin();
  tft.setRotation(3);
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);

  listDir(SPIFFS, "/", 0);
  fs::File jpeg = SPIFFS.open("/star.jpg", "r");
  //readFile(SPIFFS, "/star.jpg");
  boolean decoded = JpegDec.decodeFsFile(jpeg);
  Serial.println("===============");
  Serial.println("JPEG image info");
  Serial.println("===============");
  Serial.print  ("Width      :"); Serial.println(JpegDec.width);
  Serial.print  ("Height     :"); Serial.println(JpegDec.height);
  Serial.print  ("Components :"); Serial.println(JpegDec.comps);
  Serial.print  ("MCU / row  :"); Serial.println(JpegDec.MCUSPerRow);
  Serial.print  ("MCU / col  :"); Serial.println(JpegDec.MCUSPerCol);
  Serial.print  ("Scan type  :"); Serial.println(JpegDec.scanType);
  Serial.print  ("MCU width  :"); Serial.println(JpegDec.MCUWidth);
  Serial.print  ("MCU height :"); Serial.println(JpegDec.MCUHeight);
  Serial.println("===============");
  Serial.println("");
}

void listDir(fs::FS &fs, const char * dirname, uint8_t levels){
    Serial.printf("Listing directory: %s\r\n", dirname);

    File root = fs.open(dirname);
    if(!root){
        Serial.println("- failed to open directory");
        return;
    }
    if(!root.isDirectory()){
        Serial.println(" - not a directory");
        return;
    }

    File file = root.openNextFile();
    while(file){
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            Serial.print("  DIR : ");
            Serial.println(file.name());
            if(levels){
                listDir(fs, file.name(), levels -1);
            }
        } else {
            Serial.print("  FILE: ");
            Serial.print(file.name());
            Serial.print("\tSIZE: ");
            Serial.println(file.size());
        }
        file = root.openNextFile();
    }
}

void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
    Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\r\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path);
    if(!file || file.isDirectory()){
        Serial.println("- failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }

    Serial.println("- read from file:");
    while(file.available()){
        Serial.write(file.read());
    }
}

void writeFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path, const char * message){
    Serial.printf("Writing file: %s\r\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path, FILE_WRITE);
    if(!file){
        Serial.println("- failed to open file for writing");
        return;
    }
    if(file.print(message)){
        Serial.println("- file written");
    } else {
        Serial.println("- frite failed");
    }
}

void loop() {

}
```

Output from serial:

```
Listing directory: /
  FILE: /logo.jpg       SIZE: 16346
  FILE: /arduino.jpg    SIZE: 8426
  FILE: /star.jpg       SIZE: 3853
pjpeg_decode_init() failed with status 19 <--- here is
===============
JPEG image info
===============
Width      :0
Height     :0
Components :0
MCU / row  :0
MCU / col  :0
Scan type  :0
MCU width  :0
MCU height :0
===============
```

Comment: 19 is PJPG_NOT_JPEG https://github.com/Bodmer/JPEGDecoder/blob/master/src/picojpeg.h

Comment: you should add a test `if (jpeg)` for file existence.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I can determine uploading to SPIFFS via the Arduino IDE is broken as of the beginning of 2018. The files are uploaded but are corrupted on a read. There are a few [fixes reported](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/issues/316).  I am using a core from Dec 2017 and that works fine.